# Saving Monkeyrunner captured screenshot to internal storage?

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

Is there any way of saving the screenshot taken by MonkeyRunner's  device.takeSnapshot() to the phone's internal storage itself? This example I have seen on the net only saves it to the computer where the MonkeyRunner command is executed.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTesting/article.html#monkeyrunner_example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
device.shell('screencap -p /sdcard/sc.png')
```

this will save the screen capture to your sdcard.